# Jquery Events from a datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

My newest quest has been tough to get my hear around... I have not found a thread here to get me on the right path in my situation.

I have a single inline datepicker. I have it so the selected date will show in 3 DIV's. One for the day ("DD, d"), the other for the month ("MM"), and then the Year ("yy").

```
    <script type="text/javascript">   
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
//formatDate Requires a new date object to work 
      var myDate = new Date(dateText); 
      var myDate2 = new Date(dateText);
      var myDate3 = new Date(dateText);
//Set a new var with different format to use 
      var newFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate("DD, d", myDate); 
      var newFormat2 = $.datepicker.formatDate("MM", myDate2);
      var newFormat3 = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy", myDate3);
//Choose the div you want to replace 
      $("#apDiv1").html(newFormat); 
      $("#apDiv5").html(newFormat2);
      $("#apDiv7").html(newFormat3);
    } 
  }); 
});
</script>
```

I can't seem to get it so that when a date changes in the DIV, that 2 events will be called to post in a different DIV.. Let me focus on just the Day ("DD, d") DIV..(#apDive1).

When a date is selected on the datepicker, the date will show in (#apDiv1) in the format of "DD, d". so when this 'change' happens, it will post that date to "daypower.php" to display the sum value of that day in (#apDiv2).... AND the same change will also post "daygraph.php" to return the data in (#apDive4).

Everything I have done has failed... I am back to just the datepicker... you may have a look at [the page to visually see what I am trying to do](http://www.pvmonitor.000a.biz/demo2.php).

I tried to have the date first loaded in the page, and that dateText will assure the right event, but NO result. I am not sure at this time, so I am back at square one with a clean slate that you see above.

Thanks,

Alan

I have gone back to a very basic structure that should get results without any errors (from my understanding).

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({onSelect: function(dateText) {
            var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
            $('#apDiv1').html($.datepicker.formatDate('DD, d', myDate));
            $('#apDiv5').html($.datepicker.formatDate('MM', myDate));
            $('#apDiv7').html($.datepicker.formatDate('yy', myDate));
            $.post('dayPower.php', {choice: dateText.val}, function(data) {
                $('#apDiv2').html(data).show();
            });
            $.load('dayGraph', {choice: dateText.val}, function(data) {
                  $('#apDiv4').html().show();
            });
            $.post('monthPower.php', {choice: dateText.val}, function(data) {
                $('#apDiv6').html(data).show();
            });
            $.load('monthGraph', {choice: dateText.val}, function(data) {
                  $('#apDiv9').html().show();
            });
            $.post('yearPower.php', {choice: dateText.val}, function(data) {
                $('#apDiv8').html(data).show();
            });
            $.load('yearGraph', {choice: dateText.val}, function(data) {
                  $('#apDiv10').html().show();
            });
      }});
});
```

This then brings up issues from the PHP that should work, but NO... Take the dayPower.php as an example...

```
    <?
if(isset($_POST['choice']))
$choice = (isset($_POST['choice'])) ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("Y-m-d");
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","inverters","XXXXXX"); 
if (!$con)  { 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
mysql_select_db("inverters", $con); 

$sql = 'SELECT date, sum(power/1000) AS power '        
.'FROM feed '       
.'WHERE date = $choice';
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
echo $row['power'], '<br />'; 
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

The PHP should get the DATE in a format that mysql will read clearly, and then get the SUM values for the date, and echo into the div... but no such luck... I do not understand why.

Alan

Comment: I saw the page you provided. Looks like on changing a date, the dates are correctly updating in `#apDiv1`,`#apDiv5` and `#apDiv7` in `DD, d`, `MM` and `yy` formats correctly. Are you stuck in the posting part and displaying the sum value in `#apDiv2` and `#apDiv4`?

Comment: Yes... so when the new date comes into #apDiv1 from the datepicker, the change event will then POST 2 actions - #apDiv2 AND #apDiv4... Now apDiv2 is just a number that dayPower.php will get from mysql from the date in #apdiv1, and #apDiv4 is the chart that dayGraph.php will create from the date in #apDiv1... so the "CHANGE" in #apDiv1 will trigger 2 events to happen at once.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform some other server side operations (looks like you have some graph related functionalities) you can check the following code to see how to post, return :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
                onSelect: function(dateText, inst) 
               {


            //Do AJAX post to daypower.php if you need to perform some server side operation
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: "/path/to/daypower.php",  // The actual path to the PHP file which will handle the AJAX request
                data: { selected_date: dateText},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(json_data ) 
                {
                                    //Here json_data.result can be used.
                    //formatDate Requires a new date object to work 
                              var myDate = new Date(dateText); 
                              var myDate2 = new Date(dateText);
                              var myDate3 = new Date(dateText);
                              //Set a new var with different format to use 
                              var newFormat = $.datepicker.formatDate("DD, d", myDate); 
                              var newFormat2 = $.datepicker.formatDate("MM", myDate2);
                              var newFormat3 = $.datepicker.formatDate("yy", myDate3);
                              //Choose the div you want to replace 
                              $("#apDiv1").html(newFormat); 
                              $("#apDiv5").html(newFormat2);
                              $("#apDiv7").html(newFormat3);

                },
                beforeSend: function() 
                {
                    //display loading etc...
                },
                error: function() 
                {
                    //do something to handle error
                }
            });

        } 
      }); 
    });
    </script>
```

At the end of server side logic in the file `daypower.php`, echo a json_encoded array of the result like :-

```
   echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
```

And you will be able to get the result inside the `success` event of the AJAX post as `json_data.result`. If you want to have two separate AJAX posts to your two files, you can have nested AJAX posts like this:-

```
                   //Do AJAX post to daypower.php
               $.ajax({
                type: "POST", 
                url: "/path/to/daypower.php",  // The actual path to the PHP file which will handle the AJAX request
                data: { selected_date: dateText},
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(json_data ) 
                {
                    //another AJAX call to a separate php file
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST", 
                        url: "/path/to/daygraph.php",  // The actual path to the PHP file which will handle the AJAX request
                        data: { selected_date: dateText},
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(json_data ) 
                        {
                            //Finally perform display changes here

                        },
                        beforeSend: function() 
                        {
                            //display loading etc...
                        },
                        error: function() 
                        {
                            //do something to handle error
                        }
                    });
                },
                beforeSend: function() 
                {
                    //display loading etc...
                },
                error: function() 
                {
                    //do something to handle error
                }
            });
```

But it would be better to perform all the server side operations in a single AJAX call because every call is a separate http request and needs additional time to process.

Check [jQuery Ajax Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) for details.

**Update**

Nested post requests like you need:-

```
$.post('dayPower.php', {daDate: textDate.val() }
                    , 
                    function(data1) 
                    {
                        $.post(baseUrl+"/ajax/add_credit", {daDate: textDate.val() }
                        , 
                        function(data2) 
                        {
                         //Update both the results at a time (after both requests have responded - there will be synchronism in updation)
                            $('#apDiv2').html(data1).show();
                            $('#apDiv4').html(data2).show();
                        },"json");
                    },"json");
```

Comment: Hello, and thanks for the great input... I was trying this....$('#apDiv1').change(function() {
 $.post('dayPower.php', {daDate: textDate.val()function(data) {
 $('#apDiv2').html(data).show();... but this is only 1 of the 2 actions, I need to also post to dayGraph.php go into #apDiv4

Comment: Been trying this... Hmmmmm  $('#apDiv1').blur(function() { $.post('dayPower.php', {daDate: textDate.val()function(data); $.post('dayGraph.php', {daDate: textDate.val()function(data) } , function(data1) { $.post(baseUrl+"/ajax/add_credit", {daDate: textDate.val() } , function(data2) { $('#apDiv2').html(data1).show(); $('#apDiv4').html(data2).show(); },"json"); },"json"); }) });

Comment: One of the main issues is that, just the single click of a date on the datepicker, many events are happening ... ONE is that the dateText in #apdiv1, #apDiv5, #apDiv7 are changing to that date format. TWO is that #apDiv2, #apDiv6, #apDiv8 will reveive a value from a mysql from a a POST to PHP function. THREE is that #apDiv4, #apDiv9, #apdiv10 will receive a graph from mysql and highcharts in post to PHP function... overal 9 events happen from just one singel click... look at the page to see what I want to happen www.pvmonitor.000a.biz/demo2.php

Comment: @hkalan the code that you put in your comment "Been trying this... Hmmmmm" contains many errors.  I suggest you start from the basics. The basic code structure that I gave should work. I have understood your requirement. You need to start from simple code and then move to complex

Comment: I entered the new structure I am using that is basic at the top of the page below my first question... Alan